# INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR when trying to verify payment via paypal REST API

Tags: php, rest, paypal

I'm trying to validate a payment made through a partner service. The partner is passing me the payment id and I'm using the REST API to look it up. So far, all attempts to use the `payments/payment/<Payment-Id>` are throwing an INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR. (I'm still using the sandbox and demo user.)

Getting a token seems to be working fine:

```
curl -v https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token  -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Accept-Language: en_US" -u "EOJ2S-Z6OoN_le_KS1d75wsZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp:EClusMEUk8e9ihI7ZdVLF5cZ6y0SFdVsY9183IvxFyZp" -d "grant_type=client_credentials"
```

Response:

```
{"scope":"https://api.paypal.com/v1/developer/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/.* https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card https://api.paypal.com/v1/vault/credit-card/.*","access_token":"A015GzttpnOSOPfcqtfAaq1kdgqow5W.IXSe6TJ9Cpbesr4","token_type":"Bearer","app_id":"APP-8KK24973T6066201W","expires_in":28800}
```

Taking that token and putting into the payment request:

```
curl -v -X GET https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-8UD377151U702286RKOQ3DTQ -H "Content-Type:application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer A015GzttpnOSOPfcqtfAaq1kdgqow5W.IXSe6TJ9Cpbesr4"
```

returns the error:

```
{"name":"INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","message":"An internal service error has occurred","information_link":"https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#INTERNAL_SERVICE_ERROR","debug_id":"ca33c7679121d"}
```

UPDATE: basically I'm trying to follow the steps outlined here: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/verify-mobile-payment/

Comment: Can you clarify "partner service"?

Comment: Mobile app makes a payment to us using PayPal api. Sends us payment id. We need to validate it.